# What does "DC" stand for? (white light source)

Tags: visible-light, terminology, notation

I found [this website](https://www.waveformlighting.com/tech/color-rendering-index-calculator) where I can enter the power spectrum of a (white) light source to calculate its color rendering index (CRI).
For some of my spectra, no CRI is calculated and the desciption says, that the tool only calculates CRI values for light sources that have "a DC < 0.0054".

What does "DC" stand for in this context?

Comment: I was in the lighting business for a while and wrote my own code to calculate CRI.  I've never heard of "DC"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the english (not my native language) version of the wikipedia article about CRI I found the answer:
DC stands for "chromaticity distance".

Answer (score 0):

I would expect a DC light source to be driven by a direct current.  The light coming from an AC driven source is likely to be modulated.